# Reference .phar classes installed globally with composer

Tags: php, composer-php, phar

I've created a small command line tool in PHP and I've also packed that as a PHAR archive.

Next thing I did was publish my archive to `packagist.org` aka `composer`.

I can now install my PHAR package through composer like so:

```
composer global require acme/mypackage
```

This installs my package fine. And I'm able to run it through command as well.

So far so good, but here comes the problem I´m currently facing.

I have another project should use `acme/mypackage`. I want that project to reference a class that is packed into that PHAR. Something like this:

```
<?php
class SomeClass extends AcmeClass { 

}
```

The problem is that the PHP code doesn't recognize the `AcmeClass` class. Makes sense, because it´s obviously "globally" installed somewhere on the system.

How do other libraries solve this issue? If I'm not mistaken then PHPUnit does something similar right?

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a `composer.json` file to the root of your project:

> The first (and often only) thing you specify in composer.json is the require key. You're simply telling Composer which packages your project depends on.

```
{
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*"
    }
}
```

Next, you'll need to autoload your dependencies.

> For libraries that specify autoload information, Composer generates a vendor/autoload.php file. You can simply include this file and you will get autoloading for free.

`require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Comment: So with other words, installing it globally with composer is useless when you also want to reference class files from it? Because this is how I would normally install packages.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Installing composer globally is useful.  Everything else is managed by composer.  This helps if we have two separate projects but want two use two different versions of a dependency.